# How to create Alphabetical Group of Brands Menu by php

Tags: php, mysql

How To Create Brand List By Alphabetical Order.

I have a table...

```
Brand     Brand_link   brand_photo  brand_alt

Adam       link1        photo1       alt1
Adiddas    link2        photo2       alt2
Foscrani   link3        photo3       alt3
Zumrani    link4        photo4       alt4
Kaboche    link5        photo5       alt5
Myur       link6        photo6       alt6
```

Now I used this query...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(brand_name, 1, 1) as brand,
brand_name,brand_country,brand_photo,brand_link,brand_id 
FROM brands
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(brand_name, 0, 2) , brand_name 
ORDER BY '$alpha','$brand_name'"
```

### By this  i got this sequence of array

[image]

### But I want to create my Brand Listing like this...

[image]

I need any idea how to do this....in php with mysql

I used...this

```
foreach($results as $brand) { 
    $startsWith = strtolower($brand['brand']);

    if( array_key_exists($startsWith, $groups))
        array_push($groups[$startsWith], $brand);
    else 
    {
       foreach($results as $res){

           $groups[$startsWith] = Array($res[$startsWith]);

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO here we do not do the work for you rather we help you if you have a problem with your code. So if you have a problem with your code don't be shy and edit it in your question. Show us what you have tried what didn't work and what you expect your code to do. Then we can help you. Check out these links they are : [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please any text as text. An image is a pain for everyone to deal with.

Comment: @BRoebie I explain what i used...please help me...

Comment: @DeepakRai you forgot the curly braces at the `if` statement try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces at the `if` statement

Replace this:

```
foreach($results as $brand) { 
$startsWith = strtolower($brand['brand']);

if( array_key_exists($startsWith, $groups))
    array_push($groups[$startsWith], $brand);
else 
{
   foreach($results as $res){

       $groups[$startsWith] = Array($res[$startsWith]);

    }
  }
}
```

With this:

```
foreach($results as $brand) { 
$startsWith = strtolower($brand['brand']);

if( array_key_exists($startsWith, $groups)){
    array_push($groups[$startsWith], $brand);
 }
else 
{
   foreach($results as $res){

       $groups[$startsWith] = Array($res[$startsWith]);

    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if that is the problem please try

Comment: @DeepakRai So that solved the problem? if so glad to help and could you vote my answer please that helps me out big time

Comment: Yes i solved my problem...Can I modify you answer with ...My answer

Comment: @DeepakRai sure suggest an edit mate. but could u vote my answer please